# Raphael pie chart, putting dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, pie-chart

I want to put my dynamic data into the raphael pie chart. I can't write the following code outside window.onload() of my javascript code. Did anyone add dynamic data in the rapahael pie chart? This is my current code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var r = Raphael("holder");
        r.g.txtattr.font = "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif";
        r.g.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({"font-size": 20});
        var pie = r.g.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2], {legend: ["%%.%%" , "%%.%%","%%.%%"], legendpos: "west"});
    }
</script>
```

Insted of this 55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2 data I want to write my data returned from database in my JSP page. How can I add that? I'm having the data

```
<c:forEach var="Detail" items="${DetailRow.List.}">'${Detail.Text}',${Detail.Count}</c:forE­ach>
```

I want to add `${Detail.Text}',${Detail.Count}` into the pie chart. How can I convert it into `([[],[]..])`?

Comment: i cant add my dynamic data into Graphael pie chart . the following code doesnt work when i wrote it outside window.onload() .                              <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                
                     var  pie = r.g.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], {legend: ["%%.%%" , "%%.%%","%%.%%"], legendpos: "west"});
                </script>

Comment: Your question seems clear to me yet.

Comment: @kiran: Explain what you mean by dynamic data, and if possible write more code in your question.

Comment: @Nobita :This is my current code <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 window.onload = function () {
 var r = Raphael("holder");r.g.txtattr.font = "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif";
  r.g.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({"font-size": 20});   var  pie = r.g.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2], {legend: ["%%.%%" , "%%.%%","%%.%%"], legendpos: "west"});
   }
               </script>  Insted of this 55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2 data i want to write my data returned from database in my jsp page. how can i add that

Comment: i saw some thing like this  var labels = [];
  var values = [];
   for (i in data.items) {
     var item = data.items[i];
     labels.push(item.label);
     values.push(item.data);
   }       var pie = r.g.piechart(320, 240, 100, values, {legend: labels, legendpos: "west"});.  which array is used here(data.tems) i want to insert my data into data[] array

Comment: @kirian - please edit the main question to include all these details; people will be more likely to answer the question if all the relevant info is in the question text. :-)

Comment: @kirian - okay, great. the info is in the question. thank you. It might also be a good idea to make it readable. No-one's going to help if they have to decipher all that. Please indent it, or use the 'code' button on the editor to help you. Also, please don't keep asking the same question over and over; they'll just get closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Kiran,

If I understood you well, you want to do something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var r = Raphael("holder"),
  mydata = //AJAX call to get data from Database
  //Parse mydata to have the format you need ([[],[]..])...
  r.g.piechart(320, 240, 100,mydata);
};
```

If you could show some code **in your question** that would be nice :).  But the idea I believe is this, do an AJAX call to a script that can get data from the database.

Comment: ya this is wt i wnt, im having the data <c:forEach var="Detail" items="${DetailRow.List.}">'${Detail.Text}',${Detail.Count}</c:forEach> i want to add ${Detail.Text}',${Detail.Count} into the pie chart ? how can i convert it inot ([[],[]..]) this format ?

Comment: @kiran: Please, post that code in the main question.  That will help not just you, but the whole community.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. I am using ASP.Net MVC, But you can use any framework or language.

values, legendvalues and sectorLinkValues are .Net List object created in the page.

```
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        <% =truViewPOC.Helpers.GraphaelChartHelper.GetJavaScript(100, 150, 90, title, values, legendValues, sectorLinkValues, null) %>
     });
```

And here is my GetJavaScript method:

```
StringBuilder javaScriptBuilder = new StringBuilder();
javaScriptBuilder.Append("window.onload = function () {var r = Raphael('holder');");
AppendCenterCoordinates(ref javaScriptBuilder);

AppendLegendInfo(ref javaScriptBuilder, title);
AppendPieChartInfo(ref javaScriptBuilder, xCoord, YCoord,radius, values, legendValues,sectorLinkValues);
AppendFunctionInfo(ref javaScriptBuilder);
javaScriptBuilder.Append("}");

private static void AppendFunctionInfo(ref StringBuilder javaScriptBuilder)
        {
            javaScriptBuilder.Append("pie.hover(function () {this.sector.stop();this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);if (this.label) {this.label[0].stop();this.label[0].scale(1.5);this.label[1].attr({ 'font-weight': 800 });}}, function () {this.sector.animate({ scale: [1, 1, this.cx, this.cy] }, 500, 'bounce');if (this.label) {this.label[0].animate({ scale: 1 }, 500, 'bounce');this.label[1].attr({ 'font-weight': 400 });}}); ");
            javaScriptBuilder.Append("pie.each(function(){ this.sector.label=this.sector.value;   })");
        }
        private static void AppendPieChartInfo(ref StringBuilder javaScriptBuilder, int xCoord, int YCoord, int radius, List<decimal> values, List<string> legendValues, List<string> sectorLinkValues)
        {
            javaScriptBuilder.AppendFormat("var pie = r.g.piechart({0},{1},{2},{3},", xCoord, YCoord, radius, ConvertValuesToString(values));
            javaScriptBuilder.Append("{");
            javaScriptBuilder.AppendFormat("legend: {0}, legendpos: 'east', href:{1}",ConvertValuesToString(legendValues),ConvertValuesToString(sectorLinkValues));
            javaScriptBuilder.Append("});");
        }

private static void AppendLegendInfo(ref StringBuilder javaScriptBuilder, string title)
        {
            javaScriptBuilder.Append("r.g.text(140, 24, " + "'" + title +  "'" + ").attr({ 'font-size': 16 });");
        }

 private static string ConvertValuesToString(List<decimal> values)
        {
            string finalString = "[";


            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {
                finalString += values[i].ToString();
                if (i<values.Count-1)
                {
                     finalString+= ",";
                }


            }
            finalString += "]";
            return finalString;
```

Hope this helps..Let me know if you have any questions about this code. Thanks. Vikas
            }